# Should the smart contract be deployed at the same time as its own token?

Tags: solidity, ether

I have written a token and deployed it on the ethereum network. After 6 months I want to use that token I have deployed, in a new smart contract and make in-app payments with that token. Is it possible?

Comment: ya I think . try it on the test net .

Comment: the new contract can accept any form of payment it wants, so yes, provided the token is satisfactory.

Comment: I implemented this issue in the test net , but unfortunately it does not allow me to use the generated tokens (assuming 6 months ago) to my new smart contract. I also entered the smart contract address of the generated smart contact, but the token is not allowed to pay in the new smart contract.